# How do I know if an android app for a phone can be installed on an android tablet?

Tags: applications, tablet

Is there any way to find out? (probably using an emulator or a software to verify?) This is because from my understanding, there are android apps for phone which somehow become either stretched or remain small in screen size when installed on an android tablet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use emulator.
2. Test on hardware, because if in market you see, what application not compartible with you device - it's not 100% guarantee, it's just mean, what in application info it written.
   Most application works on tablet correctly, but some is stretched, else if tablet have needed hardware (eg GSM/3G/LTE?etc).

Comment: Just a question, which emulator would be better to be use to test such apps? (Is it the Android SDK ADB? or something else?)

Comment: Only SDK, because 3rd party emulators can have OS customizations. Also in SDK you can select standard device configuration to emulate (except market, but it can be fixed manualy).

Comment: Just a suggestion for consideration - I was wondering if it is possible for the developer or Google Play to inform the user that the apps can be use for which inch-size of phone and/or tablet. (e.g. Apps ABC max inch: 10.1, min inch: 7) In that way, at least user are better inform if the apps can be used without any display distortion.